# What is the regular expression for this "password"?

Tags: c#, regex

I want regular expression that contains at least one alphanumeric character, at least one non alphanumeric character (special character) and at least one digit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single regular expression is probably not the appropriate tool.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser I doubt this is homework, probably password validation.

Comment: Did you tried something? Any attempted regex!

Comment: @Ben I know, but its posted as a homework.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser It's not "posted as a homework". Sure, it's a badly-asked question but that doesn't make it homework. (Well-asked questions can still be tagged homework if that's what they are! Homework doesn't mean badly-asked; it means homework.)

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are welcome as long as they are asked honestly, explain the problem, and show sufficient effort

Comment: Why not just use one regex for each constriant, and validate the string against all of them?

Comment: @Pravat: you (and YetAnotherUser) have both missed the point: there is absolutely no indication that this is a homework question (other than the `homework` tag, which YetAnotherUser added, *not* the OP).

Comment: @Mac & @Ben - got the point, I was actually not clear on Homework tag. But hope you know what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer of my question :

regular Expression :

^((?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])).{8,30}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, in other words, at least one alpha, one digit, and one non-alphanum...

You need two lookaheads:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Since this is marked as homework, I suggest you actually understand it, too:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

---

In case you don't want spaces either:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*(?=\S)[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: It'll match a string that has a non-alphanum provided it also contains an alpha and a digit. If it has one of each, it can have more than one of each too.

Comment: .*[^...] That's amazing.  I would expect that to match a space.  Match zero or more characters that are not words...  I would have never expected that.  Cool.

Comment: Indeed. Though, a space was a non-alphanum last I checked. :-)

Comment: @Denis, your regex that isn't supposed to match a space will match `1A !`. the dot in `.*(?=\S)` is the culprit.

Comment: @Mel: ya, it's there to prevent the non-alphanum from catching a space, not to prevent spaces altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to pick out any one of them, but to have all three of them in any order would be something.  You could try a single character of one of the three then use look aheads for the remaining, but you would still need to check behind that character too.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework (or perhaps not?), here is a hint for a solution that doesn't use look-aheads or other nifty tricks.

In how many (and it what) permutations can the characters occur? How can this be used with the alternation (`|`) operator?

---

I would use multiple tests and not a single regex :-)

Happy coding.